# heroku container:push not update new docker image

Tags: docker, heroku

i am using `heroku container:push web` to deploy new image to heroku registry for my app. i tested my updated image on local docker, it working. But when re-deploy app with that command, it not working. Still old app state (with old code) exist, new image ignored.
So, heroku cache my app image? how can i delete cache?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku changed the behavior of `container:push` a few days ago: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1426